# Que significa y que hace un select en un insert

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta sentencia, pero mi duda es que hace el select 1, y como quedaria, algun ejemplo, que me pudieran proporcionar y explicacion.

```
 insert into grades (idStudent,idCourse)   
    select 1, id from courses where idGroup=groupId;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realizará una inserción en la tabla `grades` donde la coincidencia de `idGroup=groupId;` se cumpla.

Es decir si tu table `grades` luce así

```
idStudent,idCourse
```

Entonces al momento de realizar la query

```
insert into grades (idStudent,idCourse)   
    select 1, id from courses where idGroup=groupId;
```

La tabla debería lucir así

```
idStudent,idCourse
    1         20
```

Entendiendo que `20` es un valor de ejemplo que puede tomar dada la consulta y su última condición.

En resumen

Las columnas `idStudent` y `idCourse` se van a llenar con el número `1` como valor constante para la primer columna y para la segunda columna con el valor que resulte después de la condición `where idGroup=groupId;`

La columna `idCourse` en la tabla `grades` se va a llenar en específico con la columna de la tabla `courses`

Todo lo anterior siempre que dicha condición como ya dije se cumpla